# How does chain fishing work?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

How exactly do I chain fish in Pokemon X and Y? Do i have to talk to the super rod fisherman, or what. I fish every time after the last, but I have no way to know if it is working or not. I run at the end of every battle instead of KO'ing due to limited PP.

Comment: That's what the PP O-power is good for ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simply pick a spot and use any rod.

These actions will cause the chain to break*:

- Reeling it in too late/early
- No fish biting (use a pokemon with Suction Cups / Sticky Hold ability in the first party slot to reduce the chance of this)
- Loading/reloading a map

  - Entering a building
  - Using Fly
- Ending the game / switching the 3DS off

---

These actions **will not** cause the chain to break*:

- Running from battle
- Catching/Fainting the pokemon
- Fishing up a different pokemon
- Using Potions / Repels / PP restore from menu
- Using a different fishing rod
- Equipping the Bicycle / Dowsing Machine / Skates
- Moving to another spot on land (within the same map)

  - Encountering other Pokemon in grass.
- Crossing a map boundary as long as it does not involve doors and/or loading a map. (e.g. it is okay to move along the coast of Cyllage City, Lower Route 8, Ambrette Town)
- Using Surf and Waterfall

  - Moving from land to water using Surf
  - Moving on water
  - Encountering Water pokemon by moving on water
- Using Rock Smash

  - Encountering pokemon from the Rock Smash
- Saving the game (but this doesn't matter because the chain breaks if you switch off the game, so you can't load a save file that maintains the chain).
- Closing the 3DS lid (sleep mode)
- Pressing the home button (suspended game)

---

*A Summary on how this information was verified:

1. Started with a fishing record of 5 consecutive.
2. Fish 6 consecutive times
3. Perform the alleged action that will break the chain
4. Fish another 2 consecutive times
5. Check against the fisherman in the fishing shack on Route 16

If he reports 6 as the longest chain, then the action that was investigated breaks the consecutive chain. If he reports 8 as the longest chain, then that action does not break the chain.

Comment: Good and useful information, but didn't clearly answer the question.