# Where do you find Red Gyarados in Pokemon X/Y?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Is Red Gyarados available in Pokemon Y? If so where do I find it?

A friend told me he has it but I don't believe him but him telling me has made me curious where and how do you find it

Answer (score 9):

The red gyarados isn't unique- it's simply a shiny gyarados. There isn't a specific event for it in Y (or in any games except gen 2 and the remakes) but any way of getting a shiny pokemon will work here. Catch a shiny gyarados or evolve a shiny magikarp.

You can also transfer a red gyarados caught in Heart Gold/Soul Silver to Y, if you own one of those games.

Comment: See also: [How does chain fishing work?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/144351/how-does-chain-fishing-work) for a way to increase your chances of encountering a shiny magikarp (as the old rod will pull up *only* magikarp on routes 3, 22, and Parfum palace)